# ¿como migrar un proyecto de android a la version reciente?

Tags: android-studio

Hola sucede que tengo un proyecto creado en android 2.3.3 pero la version mas reciente es 3.1.3 y no me deja correr el proyecto, me manda el error de abajo.
Ya probe con diferentes celulares con versiones mas actualizadas de android pero sigue mandando ese error y me redirige a la documentacion de android donde dice que se debe migrar a la version mas actualizada de android porque como dije, el proyecto fue creado en la version 2.3.3 y ahora ya se actualizo a la 3.1.3 y no entiendo nada.

```html
Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
  - butterknife-6.1.0.jar (com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0)
Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
See https://developer.android.com/r/tools/annotation-processor-error-message.html for more details.
```

```html
instant run is not supported on devices with api levels 20 or lower
```

Comment: El mensaje de error se traduce por “la ejecución inmediata no está soportada en dispositivos con API de nivel 20 o inferior”. Si dices que el dispositivo es 4.4.2 con API 19 ó 20 (parece que 19 según la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4)), tendrás que probar en un dispositivo más actualizado.

Comment: ¿Has establecido tu dispositivo en modo desarrollador y activado la depuración por USB? Si es así, descarga el pack tools 25.0 de Android (debería aparecerte un cartel al ejecutarlo dirigiéndote a la actualización). También recuerda que la versión del proyecto debe ser igual o menor a la versión de tu dispositivo. De igual manera, si lo que quieres es ejecutar la APP en tu celular, simplemente ve a la pestaña "Run" y dale al "Generate .apk", vas a la carpeta donde lo crea, y pasas el archivo a tu celular (copias y pegas o te lo envías por Wpp, FB, etc...) lo descargas y ya se instala y lo pued